# Do attracted to electrode charged particles make current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

Consider a bulb with an anode. Cathode, is out of bulb.

Bulb is filled with gas.

Now, gas molecules are ionized by, for example external radiation.

Bulb should now contain "free" electrons, that should be attracted by anode.

When they will be attracted, will the current (any amount) flow in anode-cathode circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call the "circuits" because electric current flows in circles. You have no circle, so no current. You need a second electrode (cathode) in the chamber to close the circuit. Positive ions flow to the cathode, negative electrons and/or ions flow to your anode, and you get a current through the gas.

This is an [ionization chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_chamber), a common physical instrument.

Comment: What if configuration will be same, but anode will also have a “branch”, i.e. parallel connection to npn transistor? Will current flow then?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd Not sure what you mean. Draw it and see if there's a circle.